# parse string and make sure that it ontains a 9-digit number

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string

```
//webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?hl=en&amp;lr=&amp;rlz=1G1GGLQ_IWIL297&amp;q=cache:UadRLVLrpCQJ:http://www.buy.com/prod/pny-geforce-9800-gx2-1gb-512-bit-ddr3-600mhz-pci-e-2-0-dual-dvi-hdmi/207534756.html%2BVCG98GX2XPB%2Bsite%253Abuy.com&amp;ct=clnk
```

How can I check if it contains a sequence of 9-digits? In this example, it has `207534756`

I tried this:

```
String resultString = Regex.Match(i.ToString(), @"\d+").Value;
if (resultString.Length == 9){}
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `@"[0-9]{9}"`. It will match exactly 9 digits in a row.

Edit: More correctly is to also ensure that there are no other digits around: `@"(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{9}([^0-9]|$)"`

Comment: +1: This is the only answer so far that excludes Unicode digits. In .NET, you should always use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` when you only want digits 0-9.

Comment: The question did not specify anything related to content encoding however I applaud your willingness to read into the problem @ hand. Good job for giving the extra information!

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`Regex.IsMatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx) and a regular expression with a repetition length specifier:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(i.ToString(), @"\d{9}")) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I embellished in the dark side for a moment!

Answer (score 1):

Change the regex to match strings of 9 digits:

```
@"\d{9}"
```

Also, your current code doesn't work because you are using `Regex.Match` which only returns the *first* match.

You should be using `Regex.Matches` and loop over the results.

Answer (score 0):

'\d{9}'

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp which is just a good reference... there is also RegexBuddy... just Google Regex Reference

Comment: Two things: 1. See http://w3fools.com for why w3schools are not a good ref. 2. A much better reference is http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: He is a beginnner and that is in your humble opinion if I don't say so myself:P

Comment: w3fools.com rocks. I agree with that part. The poster is a beginner is what I was talking about.

Comment: So, it is OK to point a beginner at a bad resource which they might never realise is bad?

Comment: Only to allow them to come to their own conclusions as some may possibly find w3c Schools helpful for one reason or another. Regardless what you or anyone says it still does contain information which could answer his question and would empower him to search further. I am sure he appreciates your input as do I. I guess I also appreciate your willingness to get on the same page with me rather than to just take my comments in stride. Propz